# Is CIL ldstr replaced with constant reference to the string.Intern during JIT/AOT compilation?

Tags: c#, string, cil, il

Say I have a code that needs to be optimized but easy to debug at the same time.
I would thus assign a string to every value I use.
Does the string inflict a major performance hit or is it turned into a constant reference obtained from string.Intern during `JIT`/`AOT` compilation, thus turning into a single simple instruction ?

Example:

In IL it would be `ldstr "gazilion lines"`.

Is it during JIT/AOT compilation turned into something like `ldsflda string.InternCache.ID_0000647516166`
and `const string ID_0000647516166 = "gazilion lines";`
is added to `string.InternCache` ?

Yes, I could theoretically look into https://github.com/mono/mono but I have no idea how to find it.

Yes, I am mixing CIL, C# and whatever CIL is compiled into, but you get the idea.

Is `ldstr` guaranteed to be `O(1)`?

Yes it's "implementation detail" of the CLR but it would make sense if it was optimized this way.

Comment: Long answer: yes.  Becomes a single MOV reg,imm instruction at runtime, be sure to use a debugger that can show you the disassembly so you don't have to fret about how the metadata token and the jitter works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Long answer: yes. Becomes a single MOV reg,imm instruction at runtime,
>   be sure to use a debugger that can show you the disassembly so you
>   don't have to fret about how the metadata token and the jitter works.
>   – [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

Comment: Please expand on/to the individual questions.